# python virtualenv module import error

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am using virtualenv and have activated it and tested it like this:

```
source .virtualenvs/myapp/bin/activate
pip freeze

(myapp) me: redis==2.05
```

Then checking redis can import OK:

```
(myapp) me: python
>>>import redis
```

This works OK.

However on running the following

```
(myapp) me: sudo ./manage.py database create
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 4, in <module>
    from myapp import manager
  File "/home/me/myapp/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import redis
ImportError: No module named redis
```

Redis is clearly installed for the virtualenv, any thoughts on what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `sudo` is the reason. It does not properly preserve the virtualenv.

Just try to create a shell script, which first sources the environment and than executes python. Than run this shell script with the sudo command:

```
#!/bin/sh

# ensure that working directory is right
source .virtualenvs/myapp/bin/activate
./manage.py database create
```

and run it:

```
$ chmod ugo+x my-startup-shell.sh
$ sudo my-startup-shell.sh
```

If that works, do some experiments with `sudo` like possibly passing the `-E` option to inherit the environment etc.